# ¿Cómo obtener los valores de un input, selects dentro de divs con jquery?

Tags: jquery, html5, div

Resulta que tengo datos formados como una tabla pero no lo pongo en table porque va cambiando con jquery de divs(*agregando y borrando principalmente estos elementos*) entonces queda tal que así
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código con el que formo esto es este y va junto a un jquery para obtener los datos de todos esos inputs y selects. Les dejo el ejecutable para que vean como queda y que pasa al apretar el botón

```js
$("#click").click(function() {
  var columnas = [];

  $('#columnas_excel').find('div').children().each(function() {
    console.log($(this).children().val());
    columnas.push($(this).children().val());
  })
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<button id="click">Prueba</button>
<div class="card-body" id="columnas_excel">
  <div class="col-sm-12 row">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
      <input class="form-control" value="Nombre Generico1">

    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-4" id="tablasName">
      <select class="form-control" id="select_0" tabindex="-1">
        <option value="">Seleccione Tabla</option>
        <option value="tabla1">tabla1</option>
        <option value="tabla2">tabla2</option>
        <option value="tabla3">tabla3</option>
        <option value="tabla4">tabla4</option>
        <option value="tabla5">tabla5</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
      <select class="form-control" id="select_1_1" tabindex="-1">
        <option value="Columna1">Columna1</option>
        <option value="Columna2">Columna2</option>
        <option value="Columna3">Columna3</option>
        <option value="Columna4">Columna4</option>
        <option value="Columna5">Columna5</option>
        <option value="Columna6">Columna6</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="pl-3">
      <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" id="button_0">
                <i class="fa fa-trash bigfonts"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 row">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
      <input class="form-control" value="Nombre Generico2">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-4" id="tablasName">
      <select class="form-control" id="select_1" tabindex="-1">
        <option value="">Seleccione Tabla</option>
        <option value="tabla1">tabla1</option>
        <option value="tabla2">tabla2</option>
        <option value="tabla3">tabla3</option>
        <option value="tabla4">tabla4</option>
        <option value="tabla5">tabla5</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
      <select class="form-control" id="select_1_1" tabindex="-1">
        <option value="Columna1">Columna1</option>
        <option value="Columna2">Columna2</option>
        <option value="Columna3">Columna3</option>
        <option value="Columna4">Columna4</option>
        <option value="Columna5">Columna5</option>
        <option value="Columna6">Columna6</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="pl-3">
      <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" id="button_1">
                <i class="fa fa-trash bigfonts"></i>
            </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 row">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-3"><input class="form-control" value="Nombre Generico3"></div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-4" id="tablasName">
      <select class="form-control" id="select_2" tabindex="-1">
        <option value="">Seleccione Tabla</option>
        <option value="tabla1">tabla1</option>
        <option value="tabla2">tabla2</option>
        <option value="tabla3">tabla3</option>
        <option value="tabla4">tabla4</option>
        <option value="tabla5">tabla5</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
      <select class="form-control" id="select_1_1" tabindex="-1">
        <option value="Columna1">Columna1</option>
        <option value="Columna2">Columna2</option>
        <option value="Columna3">Columna3</option>
        <option value="Columna4">Columna4</option>
        <option value="Columna5">Columna5</option>
        <option value="Columna6">Columna6</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="pl-3">
      <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" id="button_2">
                <i class="fa fa-trash bigfonts"></i>
            </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Lo que pasa que con ese código me forma un array desordenado y me toma datos que yo no quiero los datos que me forma son así.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero yo lo que quiero es que los forme así (*este es un ejemplo de cómo quiero que los tome el jquery*)

- Nombre Generico1
- Tabla2
- Columna1
- "campo vacio del botón"
- Nombre Generico2
- Tabla3
- Columna1
- "campo vacio del botón"
- Nombre Generico3
- Tabla4
- Columna1
- "campo vacio del botón"

> PD: puse un boton para que prueben como es que lo muestra el console
>   log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En lugar de tratar de encontrar los `inputs` y `selects` de una forma enrevesada mediante `children` de `children`, podrias hacer:

```
$('#columnas_excel').find('input, select, button').each(function() {
    ...
});
```

De esa forma igual estas recorriendo el DOM en orden, pero solo te interesan esos tags.

```js
$("#click").click(function() {
  var columnas = [];

  $('#columnas_excel').find('input, select, button').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
    columnas.push($(this).val());
  })
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<button id="click">Prueba</button>
<div class="card-body" id="columnas_excel">
  <div class="col-sm-12 row">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
      <input class="form-control" value="Nombre Generico1">

    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-4" id="tablasName">
      <select class="form-control" id="select_0" tabindex="-1">
        <option value="">Seleccione Tabla</option>
        <option value="tabla1">tabla1</option>
        <option value="tabla2">tabla2</option>
        <option value="tabla3">tabla3</option>
        <option value="tabla4">tabla4</option>
        <option value="tabla5">tabla5</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
      <select class="form-control" id="select_1_1" tabindex="-1">
        <option value="Columna1">Columna1</option>
        <option value="Columna2">Columna2</option>
        <option value="Columna3">Columna3</option>
        <option value="Columna4">Columna4</option>
        <option value="Columna5">Columna5</option>
        <option value="Columna6">Columna6</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="pl-3">
      <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" id="button_0">
                <i class="fa fa-trash bigfonts"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 row">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
      <input class="form-control" value="Nombre Generico2">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-4" id="tablasName">
      <select class="form-control" id="select_1" tabindex="-1">
        <option value="">Seleccione Tabla</option>
        <option value="tabla1">tabla1</option>
        <option value="tabla2">tabla2</option>
        <option value="tabla3">tabla3</option>
        <option value="tabla4">tabla4</option>
        <option value="tabla5">tabla5</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
      <select class="form-control" id="select_1_1" tabindex="-1">
        <option value="Columna1">Columna1</option>
        <option value="Columna2">Columna2</option>
        <option value="Columna3">Columna3</option>
        <option value="Columna4">Columna4</option>
        <option value="Columna5">Columna5</option>
        <option value="Columna6">Columna6</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="pl-3">
      <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" id="button_1">
                <i class="fa fa-trash bigfonts"></i>
            </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 row">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-3"><input class="form-control" value="Nombre Generico3"></div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-4" id="tablasName">
      <select class="form-control" id="select_2" tabindex="-1">
        <option value="">Seleccione Tabla</option>
        <option value="tabla1">tabla1</option>
        <option value="tabla2">tabla2</option>
        <option value="tabla3">tabla3</option>
        <option value="tabla4">tabla4</option>
        <option value="tabla5">tabla5</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
      <select class="form-control" id="select_1_1" tabindex="-1">
        <option value="Columna1">Columna1</option>
        <option value="Columna2">Columna2</option>
        <option value="Columna3">Columna3</option>
        <option value="Columna4">Columna4</option>
        <option value="Columna5">Columna5</option>
        <option value="Columna6">Columna6</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="pl-3">
      <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" id="button_2">
                <i class="fa fa-trash bigfonts"></i>
            </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: uu muchas gracias por la respuesta tan pronta , me resulto de mucha utilidad.